# Problems when making index

Tags: indexing

I am using `makeidx` and my own version of `minitoc.ist` to make an index in a report. Although it is my own version of the file, they are identical. I did not want to make any changes in the original file while troubleshooting.

Basically, what I want to do is:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc} % Using or omitting this package makes no difference.
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\section{one}
\index{one}
\section{two}
\index{two}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The errors I get are:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \begin{theindex}\flushcolumns
! Undefined control sequence. \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
! Undefined control sequence. {\lneed
! Undefined control sequence. ...skip}\large\bfseries\null\hfill\relax\xhead
```

Corresponding to these lines in my `.ist` file:

```
"\\\\begin{theindex}\\\\flushcolumns\\\\parindent=0pt \n \\\\makeatletter\\\\scan@allowedfalse\n"
heading_prefix   "{\\\\lneed{8.5}\\\\vspace{\\\\baselineskip}\\\\large\\\\bfseries\\\\null\\\\hfill\\\\relax\\\\xhead{"
```

Removing the commands `\\\\flushcolumns`, `\\\\scan@allowedfalse`, `\\\\lneed{8.5}` and `\\\\xhead` results in the errors disappearing. I am just wondering what they are supposed to do, why don't they work, and whether removing them - instead of solving the problem -  will give a different result?

Comment: Maybe you need to add `\usepackage{minitoc}`.  But, really, code snippets are rarely useful in the TeX world. A complete [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is usually the best way forward.

Comment: Thank you jon, for pointing out my mistake. As you can see above, I have replaced the preamble with a minimal example that gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`minitoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc.pdf), chapter "6 Jargon":

> **`minitoc.ist`** This file contains a style for formating the index in the english documentation. It is generated when compiling
>   `minitoc.ins`.

From the description I would conclude, that this file is a helper file for the generation of the documentation and does not belong in `TDS:makeindex/` IMHO.

If you want a foreign file for your own files, then the dependencies needs to be derived, such as package that define commands, which are used in `minitoc.ist`. Examples:

- `\flushcolumns` is defined by package `multicol`.
- `\lneed` is defined in `minitoc.ins`, a quite unusual place.
- `\xhead` is defined in `minitoc.dtx`.
- Switch `\ifscan@allowed` is defined by package `doc`.

Comment: Ok. I have imported the multicol and doc packages so those errors are gone but the other two remain. The  minitoc package is installed threw MikTex 2.9. Why does my MikTex not find the functions?

Comment: @zba09ker `minitoc.ins` and `minitoc.dtx` are not "run" files, these are just files for packing/unpacking `minitoc` and generating its documentation. Such (source) files are usually *not* installed in the TeX search path. It would slow down TeX compiling and cause name clashes, if all source files would be added. Take the parts of minitoc.ist and its definitions, which you understand and want to have and copy them to your own project.