# Indexing numbers of different types

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

When I use the package `makeidx` the indexing chapter starts with the text:
"Numbers written in italic refer to the page where the corresponding entry is described; numbers underlined refer to the definition; numbers in roman refer to the pages where the entry is used."

```
%%% Preamble

\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{doc}
%%%%%% Indexing %%%%%%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
%%% Begin document
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cats}
\index{cat} Text about cats
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Which generates the 
[image: Document generated by the code]

How can I either remove this text or make the referenced pages have the specified formats?

@Andrew I am afraid that I need that package since I am using the minitoc.ist style, well my own version since I had to define some things, which needs the doc package, see [Problems when making index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229958/problems-when-making-index/230247?noredirect=1#comment551667_230247)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: As far as I can see the only way to get this message is if you are using the [doc package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doc). This package is useful only if you are producing documentation for a LaTeX package, which it sounds like you are not doing. To get rid of it simply remove `\usepackage{doc}` from your preamble. As you haven't provide a MWE it's impossible to see if this is what you doing.

Comment: @Andrew: **If** there is no further clearification by the OP, I think, you should transfer your comment to an answer, please.

Comment: The edited code shows that the guess of Andrew was correct: `\usepackage{doc}` seems to be the cause

Comment: What's the purpose of `\usepackage{doc}`?

Comment: As described in the linked thread it is needed to provide the minitoc.its style with \ifscan@allowed and \scan@allowedfalse. If not used the compilation crashes.

Comment: @Kajsa I've added a fix using the `doc` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see the only way to get this message is if you are using the doc package. This package is useful only if you are producing documentation for a LaTeX package, which it sounds like you are not doing. To get rid of it simply remove `\usepackage{doc}` from your preamble. As you haven't provide a MWE it's impossible to see if this is what you are actually doing.

**Edit** If you really need to use the `doc` package then you can remove/change this message using `\IndexPrologue`:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{doc}
%%%%%% Indexing %%%%%%
\IndexPrologue{\section*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}% section heading, no message
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
%%% Begin document
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cats}
\index{cat} Text about cats
\printindex
\end{document}
```

to give:

[image]